# Image texture issue

Tags: textures, webgl, x3d, x3dom

I've found an issue when deleting a texture from a sphere. I have created a sphere with a texture and it works. Then, I duplicated this file and take the duplicated file and delete the texture from it. After that deletion all the texture in all local files do not appear!

In addition, when  I try to open similar files via internet it works again. What is wrong?

Here are 2 images describing the situation. Note the URLs.

- [The file which is opened within website](http://postimage.org/image/26lkcvzqc/).
- [local file](http://postimage.org/image/26lm0fc84/).

Answer (score 1):

Due to the cross-domain restrictions on texture loading, you need to serve the image file from the same domain as the html page. Also I believe that if you load the html and image from local file system using "file:///" url, it won't be successful. You will get a SECURITY error depending upon which browser you are using.

Read more about cross-domain restriction on texture loading [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/06/cross-domain-webgl-textures-disabled-in-firefox-5/).